# What's this notation about partitions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, set-partition

Im reading a book and somewhere it says:

> A partition of a set $A$ is a family of subsets of $A$, $\{A_a\}_{a\in I}$ such that

Where $I=\{x\mid x=1,\ldots,n\}$.

- $A_a\neq A_b\implies A_a\cap A_b=\emptyset$
- ...

What does it mean? Does family just mean set? Is $\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}$, $\{\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}\}$ or $\{\{A_1\},\ldots,\{A_n\}\}$ a partition of $A$?

Comment: Maybe check the definition of the partition of a set? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A family of subsets of $A$ just means a set whose elements are all subsets of $A$. So, a partition would look something like $\{A_1, ..., A_n\}$, where each $A_i \subseteq A$.

Note that there need not only be finitely many sets in the family (although in your case, there is). In that case, we introduce the notion of an indexing set. In the example above, our indexing set would be $\Bbb{N}_n$ (the set of all natural numbers less than or equal to $n$); this is to say, for each $i\in \Bbb{N}_n$, there is a set $A_i$ in the family.

Comment: In general a set of subsets of a set $A$ and a family of subsets of $A$ are different things: the first is a subset of the power set $P(A)$, while the second is a not necessarily injective mapping $i:I\rightarrow P(A)$, where $I$ is a set - the indexing set. To define a partition of $A$ there is no need to use the notion of a family, even in the infinite case not.

Answer (score 1):

A partition of a set $A$ is simply a collection/set of **disjoint** subsets (i.e. for any pair of subsets in the collection, their intersection is zero) of $A$ such that their union is $A$.

For example, let $P$ be partition of $A$ into $n$ parts, then $P=\{A_1,A_2,...A_n\}$ where $A_1\cup A_2\cup...\cup A_n = A$ and $A_i\cap A_j = \emptyset, \forall A_i\neq A_j$.

Depending upon the usage, $P$ may or may not be allowed to contain the empty set. The former case might be referred to as a *weak partition*.

Regarding your confusion:

> A partition of a set $A$ is a family of subsets of $A$, $\{A_a\}_{a\in I}$ such that
>
> Where $I=\{x\mid x=1,\ldots,n\}$.

This means that the partition is made up of $n$ subsets of $A$, denoted by $\{A_a| \forall a \in \{1,2,...n\}$. This is the same as the definition given above, just that it is in different("set-builder") notation.